# About electricity flow through a diode

Tags: electric-circuits, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I have read answer of Vintage in 11 July 2011 on Krzysztof Lewko's question
[Why can electricity flow only in one direction through a diode?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12089/)

I appreciate very much this answer and i vote as "this answer is useful" although my vote did not matter (only was recorded) . Also i could not add a comment because i must have 50 reputation. So i decided to make a question based on  Vintage's answer on Krzysztof Lewko's question

One part of the answer is:

> "Now, if you apply a positive voltage to the p-type and a negative at the n-type, e- in the p-type are removed, making free holes. Simultaneously, the positive voltage is conteracting the reverse voltage which had been set up in the PN junction, and e- in the n-type are force closer to the p-type, where they can cross over and fill up the new holes. Current flows.
> If, however, you apply positive voltage to the n-type, and negative to the p-type ("reverse-biasing" the diode) you simply reinforce the voltage gradient which was already naturally set up in the PN junction. The e- are forced even farther away from the PN junction, and the insulative boundary (depletion region) thickens. No current flows."

I cannot understand why when apply  positive voltage on the p-type and a negative at the n-type ("forward-biasing" the diode), the positive voltage it forces e- in the n-type so they removing closer to the p-type, where they can cross over and fill up the new holes that have been made due to the re-movement of e- in the p-type (after voltage have been applied) so current flows, BUT when apply  positive voltage to the n-type, and negative to the p-type ("reverse-biasing" the diode), the same positive voltage (but in reversed side) cannot make (except e- on n-type) the e- on p-type to move toward it (i mean attract them) so these ( the e- on p-type) can cross over, passing the depletion region and the  current to flow?

Comment: If someone asks: "why did you vote it as "useful" if you did not fully understand it" my answer is: because its explanatory structure is fully functional and therefore very usable to fulfill the purpose for which it was created. The fact that I have not fully understood it is not prohibitive for me to believe that it is right and very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Generally there must be a continuous "channel" of "holes" (positively charged "positions") that tend to "ask for"–to attract free electrons to "inhabit them"–to fill them up.
We can also imagine that the negative terminal of a power supply, such as a battery, has an excess of free electrons, and the positive one has "holes", and when a semiconductor joins the negative to the positive terminal, electrons flow from the negative to the positive terminal, through the semiconductor, to fill up the holes.
The energy of battery may be became zero when there are no more free electrons on the negative terminal and no more free "holes" on the positive terminal.

Now, when we "forward-biasing" the diode and applying positive voltage on the p-type and negative at the n-type, free electrons from the negative terminal of the power supply (battery) repel free electrons of the n-type section of the diode, so if the battery Voltage is enough high, the electrons cross over the junction and fill up the holes of the p-type section of the diode and then, fill up the holes of the positive terminal of the battery. This can be happen because there is a
continuous "channel" of "holes", through the p-type section of the diode and right away trough the positive terminal of the battery. So we have a flow of current.

Contrary, if we apply positive voltage to the n-type, and negative to the p-type ("reverse-biasing" the diode), the free electrons of the n-type section of the diode are attracted by the free "holes" of the positive terminal of the battery and move there to fill up these holes, and free electrons from the negative terminal of the battery are attracted by the free "holes" of the p-type section of the diode and move there to fill up these "holes". After these electrons (from the Ve- of the battery) fill up the p-type section's "holes", then there is no need they move further because there are no other "holes" somewhere near there. In the adjacent part of the n-type there are no "holes" to create a continuous channel of "holes" (along with  the p-type section's "holes").
So we don't have a flow of current.